# Flood Fill Algorithm with iteration

Tags: c, flood-fill

I have been working on my homework and i need flood fill algorithm in c but recursion,structures and any library(except stdio.h) is not alowed,i am allowed to use only iteration. I have been working on it for 3 days but i couldn't do it, i need help

> oldTeam(global variable) is target color
>
> newTeam(global var.) is replacement color
>
> x and y(both global) are row and colomn of the starting point of flood fill
>
> pX and pY are variables to store initial coordinates of starting point

and the function hasNeighbor(x,y) is search whether there are any color whic is target color:

```
 int hasNeighbor(int x,int y)
{
    if(table[x+1][y]==oldTeam || table[x+1][y+1]==oldTeam || table[x+1][y-1]==oldTeam || table[x][y+1]==oldTeam || table[x][y-1]==oldTeam || table[x-1][y]==oldTeam || table[x-1][y-1]==oldTeam || table[x-1][y+1]==oldTeam)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;

    }
```

Where is mistake in my code or algorithm

(Before asking this question i had been searching this topic on this site and google but the solutions which i found contains recursion,structure or not allowed library)

Thank you..

Comment: You should avoid using goto wherever possible (meaning almost everywhere).

Comment: @Eregrith yes i know it also i dont have experience about goto but this is final version of my code, and i have tried million different thing and i got million fail

Comment: It's ok to fail, it happens to everyone. Don't worry, you'll get it sometimes soon. In the meantime, keep bad habits outside ;)

Comment: Does "structure" mean e.g. an array containing visited points?

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen No, i mean struct http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_structures.htm these are not alowed

Comment: The standard way to implement an iterative flood fill is to manually track pixels that need to be checked in a container (array/stack/queue etc...). You may be able to use a fixed size `int` array but it would have to be twice the size of your image which is very large in your case. There is the [fixed memory flood fill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill#Fixed_memory_method_.28right-hand_fill_method.29) but that seems very complex for a homework question. Are you sure you need to implement a true flood fill and not just a more simple color replacer?

Comment: Yup, that sounds like a flood fill, assuming the persuasion stops when you encounter an existing fan of the new team or another team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make one pass over all the elements in your array. Determine which ones need changing according to their neighbours and change them. Keep track whether you have any changes, and if there were any changes then do it again.

```
bool anyChange; 
do { 
    anyChange = false; 
    ... change what needs changing
} while (anyChange);
```

Not particularly efficient in extreme cases, but simple and works.

Comment: i see but when one cell changed then its neighbours considered neighbour how can i change them

Comment: and also they give me 1000x1000 matrix unfortunately :(